# FFmpeg How to use alimiter Filter?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I cannot find enough documentation on the alimiter filter.

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alimiter

I used -filter_complex alimiter=limit=0.5 and it applied to the file but it boosted the volume.

I thought it was supposed to hardlimit the volume down?

FFmpeg says through cmd limit range [0.0625 - 1]

```
ffmpeg -i audio.wav -y -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 320k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -joint_stereo 1 -filter_complex alimiter=limit=0.5 audio.mp3
```

Here's a look at the two files through Adobe Audition

**Original**

[image: Original File]

**FFmpeg alimiter 0.5**

[image: FFmpeg alimiter File]

Answer (score 5):

I found the problem was here:

**level**

```
Auto level output signal. Default is enabled. This normalizes audio back to 0dB if enabled.
```

I tried chaining the filter like this using level=disabled

```
-filter_complex alimiter=level_in=1:level_out=1:limit=0.5:attack=7:release=100:level=disabled
```

It now hard limits without raising the volume.

Comment: Note that alimiter adds a delay to the audio equal to the attack parameter.